# Powershell ForEach Export Issues

Tags: powershell, foreach

1st I want to thank you for all the knowledge you share.
2nd I want to apologize in advance if this has been posted previously.

I'm kinda new to the world of PowerShell using ForEach statements. Below is my query in which I'm just trying to combine results from 2 commands in 1 csv file. It works fine when I do it on a single email address but I get **"System.Object[]"** when attempting to export 5 results - below is image of result.

```
$OutputLarge1 = @()
$MailboxesLarge1  = Get-EXOmailbox -ResultSize 5 | Select 
DisplayName,Alias,UserPrincipalName,PrimarySmtpAddress 
$StatisticsLarge1 = Get-EXOMailbox -ResultSize 5 | Get-EXOmailboxstatistics  | Select 
Displayname,DeletedItemCount,ItemCount

Foreach ($i in $MailboxesLarge1) {
    $OutputLarge1 += [PSCustomObject] @{
        DisplayName          = $MailboxesLarge1.DisplayName
        Alias                = $MailboxesLarge1.Alias
        PrincipalName        = $MailboxesLarge1.UserPrincipalName
        PrimarySmtpAddress   = $MailboxesLarge1.PrimarySmtpAddress
        DeletedItemCount     = $StatisticsLarge1.DeletedItemCount
        ItemCount            = $StatisticsLarge1.ItemCount
    }
}

$OutputLarge1 | Export-Csv C:\ForEachTestLarge.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[Image of CSV Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4gkV.jpg)

Any tips on pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This happens as the iteration is not working as intended. There are two issues. Let's take a closer look with added comments in code:

```
# Iterate all members of $MailboxesLarge1 collection
# On each iteration, $i will contain an object
Foreach ($i in $MailboxesLarge1) {
    # Add new element to $OutputLarge1
    $OutputLarge1 += [PSCustomObject] @{

        # DisplayName property will get a value of the whole collection
        # instead of iterated item $i
        DisplayName          = $MailboxesLarge1.DisplayName

        Alias                = $MailboxesLarge1.Alias
        PrincipalName        = $MailboxesLarge1.UserPrincipalName
        PrimarySmtpAddress   = $MailboxesLarge1.PrimarySmtpAddress
        DeletedItemCount     = $StatisticsLarge1.DeletedItemCount
        ItemCount            = $StatisticsLarge1.ItemCount
    }
}
```

The first issue.

So what happens is that for every item `$i` you accidentally assign the whole collection's worth of items to the output object.

Fixing is easy enough, refer to the iterator object within the loop.

The second issue is that statistics are in another a collection, and those are being accessed with the same mistake. But there's more: there is no link between the result sets. I don't have Exchange at hand, but am pretty sure there is no guarantee that the result sets are ordered. To keep the resultset the same, save the mailboxes in a variable and pass that around. Like so,

```
$boxes = Get-EXOmailbox -ResultSize 5 

$MailboxesLarge1  = $boxes|Select DisplayName,Alias,UserPrincipalName,PrimarySmtpAddress 
$StatisticsLarge1 = $boxes|Get-EXOmailboxstatistics |Select  Displayname,DeletedItemCount,ItemCount
```